# get the number of bank-notes of the sum calculation

Tags: php

Hi I am trying implement the algorithm that counts how many banknotes are in provided sum of money. For example:

Sum of money is 135 Euros
The result would be: 
1 note of 100 Euros 
1 Notes of 20 Euros 
1 Note of 10 Euros
1 Note of 5 Euros

I have the algorithm that I know works just fine as I have tested it in other language, but for some reason it gives me a wrong result on php. No matter what number I pass to function it always returns 685. Would anybody know why this would be happening? Thanks for any help.

```
<?php 

function getNotes($moneystart){
   $works = 0;
   $attempt = 0;
   $moneystart = 0;
   $money = 0;
   $p500 = 0;
   $p100 = 0; 
   $p50 = 0; 
   $p20 = 0; 
   $p10 = 0; 
   $p5 = 0; 
   $p1=0;

   while($works == 0){

   $money = $moneystart;

    if ($attempt <= 0){
        $p500 = $money / 500;
        $money = $money % 500;
    }

    if ($attempt <= 1){
        $p100 = $money / 100;
        $money  = $money % 100;
    }

    if($attempt <= 2){
        $p50 = $money/50;
        $money = $money%50;
    }

    if($attempt <= 3){
       $p20 = $money/20;
       $money = $money%20;
    }

    if($attempt <= 4){
        $p10 = $money/10;
        $money = $money%10;
    }

    if($attempt <= 5){
       $p5 = $money/5;
       $money = $money%5;
    }

    if($attempt <= 6){
      $p1 = $money;
      $works++;
    }

    if ($p500 + $p100 + $p50 + $p20 + $p10 + $p5 + $p1 >= 4){ 
        $works++;
    }

    else {
        $attempt++;
    }

    if($attempt > 6){
      echo "the amount is too little, please enter a higher value";
    }

   }

   $result  = "Result: "+"\n" 
            + $p500 + " 500e notes,"+"\n" 
            + $p100 + " 100e notes " +"\n"
            + $p50 + " 50e notes" +"\n"
            + $p20 + " 20e notes" +"\n"
            + $p10 + " 10e notes" +"\n"
            + $p5 + " 5e notes";

    echo $result;          

}

?>
```

Comment: Missing some floor() calls. `$p500 = floor($money / 500);` for example. You'll need to do it on all the divisions.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix it. But just wondering what difference does it make without floor()...Sorry for possible silly question, just have not used php that much for algorithms

Comment: Just that I thought `$p500` was meant to represent the number of 500 notes and you can't have fractions of notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.

You're overwriting the $moneystart parameter near the top of your program. Comment out $moneystart = 0;

And the PHP concatenation operator is . not +

```
<?php 

function getNotes($moneystart){
   $works = 0;
   $attempt = 0;
   //$moneystart = 0;
   $money = 0;
   $p500 = 0;
   $p100 = 0; 
   $p50 = 0; 
   $p20 = 0; 
   $p10 = 0; 
   $p5 = 0; 
   $p1=0;

   while($works == 0){

   $money = $moneystart;

    if ($attempt <= 0){
        $p500 = $money / 500;
        $money = $money % 500;
    }

    if ($attempt <= 1){
        $p100 = $money / 100;
        $money  = $money % 100;
    }

    if($attempt <= 2){
        $p50 = $money/50;
        $money = $money%50;
    }

    if($attempt <= 3){
       $p20 = $money/20;
       $money = $money%20;
    }

    if($attempt <= 4){
        $p10 = $money/10;
        $money = $money%10;
    }

    if($attempt <= 5){
       $p5 = $money/5;
       $money = $money%5;
    }

    if($attempt <= 6){
      $p1 = $money;
      $works++;
    }

    if ($p500 + $p100 + $p50 + $p20 + $p10 + $p5 + $p1 >= 4){ 
        $works++;
    }

    else {
        $attempt++;
    }

    if($attempt > 6){
      echo "the amount is too little, please enter a higher value";
    }

   }

   $result  = "Result: "."\n" 
            . $p500 . " 500e notes,"."\n" 
            . $p100 . " 100e notes " ."\n"
            . $p50 . " 50e notes" ."\n"
            . $p20 . " 20e notes" ."\n"
            . $p10 . " 10e notes" ."\n"
            . $p5 . " 5e notes";

    echo $result;          

}


getNotes(150);

/**
Output 
Result: 
0.3 500e notes,
1.5 100e notes 
1 50e notes
0 20e notes
0 10e notes
0 5e notes
*/ 


?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was some silly mistake. This fixed the problem